# Select CSS programmatically

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to define CSS rules for HTML elements placed at the same level, without the option to manipulate the html. Specifically, the need is to use the li elements with classes that contain the string "section_break" to delimitate the groups. I don't know in advance the number of sections nor the number of li elements in each section.

For example;

```
<fieldset class="multistep-fieldset">

    <li class="section_break"></li>

    <li class="background_color field-size-large"></li>          
    <li class="background_image field-size-large"></li>

    <li class="section_break_1"></li>
    
    <li class="main_image field-size-large"></li>

    <li class="section_break_2"></li>
    
    <li class="main_image field-size-large"></li>
    <li class="main_image field-size-large"></li>

</fieldset>
```

I have to group the css rules from section_break to section_break_1, then from section_break_1 to section_break_2 and so on. In the example, the first 3 li elements (including the li with class section_break) are all part of the first section, the following 2 li elements are part of the second  section, the last 3 li elements are part of the third section. I need to draw borders that cover each of them separately.

Is there an easy method for doing that using only CSS?

The closer answer looks like that; [CSS selection for the random number of elements](https://codepen.io/obenseven/pen/oNMeRvg)
Thank you for @m.piras for that solution. But, still needs to add a border to the bottom of the boxes till the last.

P.S. Unfortunately, I can't manipulate HTML elements, because they are generated automatically with code. I also don't know in advance how many sections and elements per section I will end up having.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/obenseven/pen/oNMeRvg)

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: it sounds like your markup needs to be updated so that it will reflect the intended grouping/organization/hierarchy—e.g. nested list items. For example, why is `<li>` being used as a decorative element for a section break? This isn't something CSS should be doing for you.

Comment: @Terry Unfortunately I can't manipulate HTML elements, because they are generated automatically with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/#:%7E:text=The%20%3Anth%2Dof%2Dtype,with%20parent%20and%20sibling%20elements) selector.
For example:

```
li:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

will place a border on top of the first *li* element

**EDIT**

If you don't know how many *section_break* elements you're going to have in your page you can add a combination of [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors) and [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), like in the following ([codepen](https://codepen.io/tidabliu/pen/poZWbYb)):

```
li[class*="section_break"]{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px solid black;
}

li[class*="section_break"] ~ :not(li[class*="section_break"]) { 
  border-top: 0px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px solid black;
}


li[class*="section_break"] ~ :last-of-type:not(li[class*="section_break"]) {
  border-top: 0px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li[class*="section_break"] ~ 
:not(li[class*="section_break"]):has(+ li[class*="section_break"]){
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

The first block selects every *li* that contains the string *section_break* in their class attribute; the second block selects their adjacent *li* that don't have *section_break* in their class attribute; the third block selects the last iteration of the adjacent *li* that don't have *section_break* in their class attribute; the last block adds a border to the last of each group based on the next sibling having *section_break* in its class.

Comment: You're right. I can do that with nth-of-type or a combination with first-of-type and last-of-type.

[link](https://codepen.io/obenseven/pen/oNMeRvg)

But, think like that; if we don't know how much li is generated by the code and if we can select them only with the class section_break, section_break_1, section_break_2, etc.

Maybe we need some js for to do that. But I'm curious whether there is any other way to solve this issue with CSS. Maybe, using variables in CSS or something like that.

Comment: I edited the solution. Adding attribute selectors and adjacent siblings combinators I think you will be able to obtain what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the Codepen pin: [select random count of elements](https://codepen.io/obenseven/pen/oNMeRvg). Could you take a look at that? How can I add a bottom border to the boxes till the last?

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer to add a last block taht does what you're asking

Comment: Cool. I learned a lot with this quick Q/A session. Thank you  very much m.piras.
Keep in touch! ✌